# Django inspectdb not creating primary keys

Tags: django

When I run `python manage.py inspectdb --database totals > modelstest.py` it appears to function as expected and I get my models, but it does not create primary keys and add an id field although everything I can find online says it does, little confused. I went into my settings file and added `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD='django.db.models.AutoField'` but now when I try to migrate again there is nothing to migrate, I flushed my db and tried to migrate again but it didn't really do anything, a little confused how I can migrate again to kick in that auto field setting now?

Generated model:

```
class Nbav8(models.Model):
    home_team_field = models.TextField(db_column='HOME TEAM:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_field = models.TextField(db_column='AWAY TEAM:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    projected_points_field = models.FloatField(db_column='PROJECTED POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_injury = models.TextField(db_column='Home Injury', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    away_injury = models.TextField(db_column='Away Injury', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    game_points_with_formula_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='GAME POINTS WITH FORMULA:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    game_money_line_field = models.FloatField(db_column='GAME MONEY LINE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    over_or_under = models.TextField(db_column='OVER OR UNDER', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'nbav8'
```

Removed the managed field per comment.

Comment: The models generated by `inspectdb` will be [unmanaged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#managed) so they will be ignored by migrations, you'll need to remove `managed = False` from the Meta for each model you want to manage with migrations.

Comment: Can you add one of the generated models to your question? Why do you expect `inspectdb` to add an `id` field?

Comment: Well I had thought all models need a primary key? If one was not present then django would create one?

Comment: If an `id` field is automatically generated, it may not be added to the code for the model, it's just implicitly added by Django. What's the result of running `Nbav8._meta.get_fields()` in a shell, see if there is an `id` field?

Comment: Trying that now, I run this project on a linux box in the cloud so actually unsure how to run that to be honest. I don't think it had an id field as I have some views setup on my site that pull the pk, I set it up initially manually to a field to get a few things going, I then realized I wanted an id field as pk as it would help iterate through things. That is when I realized even if I added an id field in mysql db it would not show up even when I did an inspectdb so that made me even more confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to get this working by adding an auto incrementing id field in the mysql database. I also set the model up as managed = True

```
class Nbav8(models.Model):
    home_team_field = models.TextField(db_column='HOME TEAM:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_field = models.TextField(db_column='AWAY TEAM:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    projected_points_field = models.FloatField(db_column='PROJECTED POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_injury = models.TextField(db_column='Home Injury', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    away_injury = models.TextField(db_column='Away Injury', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    game_points_with_formula_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='GAME POINTS WITH FORMULA:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    game_money_line_field = models.FloatField(db_column='GAME MONEY LINE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    over_or_under = models.TextField(db_column='OVER OR UNDER', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'nbav8'
```

I now have a pk from the auto incrementing id field from my db, note that it does not show as a model field, that was confusing me as well but it is there as a primary key.